# C++ How to store xml string in xml column in SQL database (Bindparameter)

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, xml, database

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio offers the type xml for columns. I can't figure out how to convert my data in C++ to store it in the database.

```
...
SQLTCHAR* lpStmt = reinterpret_cast<SQLTCHAR*>(_T("UPDATE MYTABLE SET XMLCOL=? WHERE ID=?"));
...
SQLLEN cbXmlString = Ind(XmlString);
SQLBindParameter(hStmt, Param++, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, 0, 0, const_cast<LPWSTR>(XmlString), strtlen(XmlString), &cbXmlString);
assert(SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret));
...
ret = SQLExecute(hStmt); //returns -1
```

I also tried it with a wchar vector. But this also returns -1 on `SQLExecute`

```
std::vector<std::wstring> XmlBinary;
data.assign(XmlString.begin(), XmlString.end());
ret = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, Param++, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_VARBINARY, 0, 0
        const_cast<std::wstring*>(&XmlBinary[0]), XmlBinary.size(), &len);
```

None of these work. What are the correct parameters for the data types in `SQLBindParameter` instead of `SQL_C_WCHAR` and `SQL_VARCHAR`? Which data type do I need in c++? Maybe this is not possible with a wstring/vector of wchar?

Comment: Use SqlDbType.NChar which is a 16 bit character.  SQL_C_WCHAR is also a wide character which is 16 bits.  SQL_VARCHAR is a variable length string that is 8 bits.  NVarChar is a string with 16 bit characters.

Comment: @jdweng SQL Server's `nchar` and `nvarchar` can be variable length encoding as well. In most collations `nchar` and `nvarchar` use UCS-2 encoding, two bytes per code point covering only the Basic Multilingual Plane code points. If the database/column is using one of the *_SC (Supplementary Character) collations then `nchar` and `nvarchar` use variable length UTF-16 encoding, where each code point from the entire Unicode set can be encoded as two or four bytes.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning : I got my answer from comments in the Net Library definitions of db types.

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time Microsoft documentation was wrong. Most of the MSDN documentation from the 2000-2005 era covering Windows NT, 2000, etc., used UCS-2 and UTF-16 interchangeably because the writers and editors didn't know any better.

Comment: Tank you, it's working with `SQLBindParameter(hStmt, Param++, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_WVARCHAR, SQL_SS_LENGTH_UNLIMITED, 0, const_cast<LPWSTR>(XmlString), strtlen(XmlString), &cbXmlString);`